# Thumbnails not generated because of PIL or Pillow?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

Thumbnails are not being generated when I upload images via the admin (I am using Django).
I think it is an issue of either PIL or Pillow, but I do not know exactly what (I think I am using both, not sure since I am using another app).

How would I go about correctly uninstalling and re-installing (or making configurations) PIL and/or Pillow so that the thumbnails will be generated? (I am using a virtualenv)

EDIT: This is the error (traceback) I am receiving from Django.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/family/.virtualenvs/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/family/.virtualenvs/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 206, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/family/.virtualenvs/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 15, in get_response
    return serve(request, path, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
  File "/home/family/.virtualenvs/virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 55, in serve
    raise Http404(_('"%(path)s" does not exist') % {'path': fullpath})
Http404: "media/product/.thumbnails/img_name" does not exist
```

Comment: which operating system do you use which python version and is there an error in the log files?

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu 13.10 with Python 2.7.5. The error states that there is a 500 Internal Server Error from getting the thumbnail image in the directory (which it cannot do since the thumbnail was never generated).

Comment: Does Django generate an error? Try setting `DEBUG = True` to see what the real error message is.

Comment: Yes, Django generates an error, but it does not crash (keeps on running), only the file cannot be served.
I edited my post to show the exact error I am receiving.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view somewher in the code somebody wrote

```
os.path.join(thumbnail_folder, 'img_name')
```

instead of

```
os.path.join(thumbnail_folder, img_name)
```

can you try looking for such an error? Focus on `'img_name'`